# Where is my netbeans bin folder?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, bin

Im using netbeans 7.3 to program java, but I don't know where the bin is to save images and stuff like that. Could anyone tell me?

Comment: Your question is not very clear... what bin? What do you want to do with these images?

Comment: What Operating System are you using and I think you mean Netbeans Project bin folder, it is not names bin folder, but "dist". You can store projects images into separate directory under src.

Answer (score 2):

Have a Look at this question: [Add resources to a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633244/add-resources-to-a-jar/16633335#16633335)

There you can find a answer where you should add your images.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding location of Netbeans \bin directory, please select the Netbeans desktop icon with your mouse and right-click. In the new window displayed select "Properties" (it is shown at the bottom).
The "Target" directory will be displayed indicating the location of Netbeans \bin directory you are looking. For example:
"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\bin\netbeans64.exe"

Regarding handling of images, Netbeans provides a tutorial regarding "Handling images in a Java GUI Application":
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html